# how to print spark rdd struct data and save to local file

Tags: scala, rdd

the rdd data is key,value format, and value is struct data 
how can i print it the first 100 datas,and save it to as local file.

it may user `rdd.take(10).saveAsTextFile`,but it would report error.

Comment: what is the error and what is the dataType of rdd ? can we see some sample lines

Comment: res1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, com.UserProfiles.UserTags)] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at UserProfiles.scala:52

Comment: and UserTags is such as struct usertags{ int a,int b,inc};

Comment: take returns an array and saveAsTextFile is a  function for rdd. And rdd should of RDD[String] to be used with saveAsTextFile. So make sure you have these two points in mind before proceeding

Comment: so how can i save to local file if i want to take some data from rdd

Comment: I have tried to answer it. please have a look

Answer (score 0):

If you use `take` on `rdd` as

```
rdd.take(10)
```

It will return you an `Array` instead of `rdd` and `saveAsTextFile` won't work with Array.

What you can do is use `zipWithIndex` for the filtering and save the filtered as

```
rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(_._2 < 100).map(_._1).saveAsTextFile("path to the output file")
```

Here `_._2 < 100` is used as you said you want to save *the first 100 data*